# How to create variable array name in foreach loop for perl

Tags: arrays, perl, foreach

I would like to create an array inside foreach loop that change name itself

```
our $j = 1;

foreach $key ( sort keys %hash ){
    @array1 = $hash{$key};
    $j++;
}
```

How to i change array name with `$j`. Like every key my array name will change from `@array1, @array2, @array3....`

Comment: Whenever you think you want a series of variables named `var1`, `var2`, `var3`, ..., just use an array instead (`var[0]`, `var[1]`, `var[2]`, ...).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would require [symbolic references](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Symbolic-references) and you [*don't want to be doing that*](https://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html). 
It is a dangerous feature which is actually needed and used only very rarely for very specific reasons. For all other purposes there are other, better, ways.

Instead, use anonymous arrays (or array [references](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)) stored in [a data structure](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html), with an array

```
my @data;
foreach $key (sort keys %hash) {
    push @data, [ ... ];          # (populate with $hash data) 
}
```

or a hash

```
my %data;
foreach $key (sort keys %hash) {
    my $name     = ...;            # work out a suitable key-name
    $data{$name} = [ ... ];        # populate with $hash data
}
```

I don't know what to put in anonymous arrays `[ ... ]`, or what good names for keys (`$name`) are, since it's not stated what is in the hash.

It is conceivable that your hash values themselves are in fact arrayrefs, in which case

```
my @data;
foreach $key (sort keys %hash) {
    push @data, $hash{$key}; 
}
```

seems to fit the question but is really just

```
my @data = map { $hash{$_} } sort keys %hash;
```

or, if you don't need a predictable order based on keys

```
my @data = values %hash;
```

But I presume that there is more to do with hash's data before it is stored in arrays.

Then you can refer to the individual array(ref)s by index (or by name in the case of a hash).

Answer (score 0):

```
for(my $i=0;$i<100;$i++){
my @arr_i=($i);
print(@arr_i,"\n");
 }
```